# Where to put popup code

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, popup

So I'm making a GUI menu with drop downs. I wanted to have the GUI create a popup window whenever the user selects an option from the drop down menu. Should I put the code for the popup within the actionPerformed method or make a separate method and call it somewhere else?

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class FinalGUI2 extends JApplet{
private JTextField text = new JTextField(10);

private ActionListener listen = new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

    }
};

private JMenu[] menu = {new JMenu("Food"), new JMenu("Fluid"), new     JMenu("Sleep")};

private JMenuItem[] items = {new JMenuItem("Add"), new JMenuItem("Add"), new JMenuItem("Add"),
        new JMenuItem("Edit"), new JMenuItem("Edit"), new JMenuItem("Edit"),
        new JMenuItem("Delete"), new JMenuItem("Delete"), new JMenuItem("Delete")};

public void init(){
    for(int i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
        items[i].addActionListener(listen);
        menu[i%3].add(items[i]);
    }
    JMenuBar bar = new JMenuBar();
    for(int i = 0; i < menu.length; i++)
        bar.add(menu[i]);
    setJMenuBar(bar);
    Container contain = getContentPane();
    contain.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    contain.add(text);
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    run(new FinalGUI2(), 200, 75);
}

public static void run(JApplet app, int width, int height){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(app);
    frame.setSize(width, height);
    app.init();
    app.start();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In the `JMenuItem`'s `ActionListener`. Maybe have a look at [How to Use Menus](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html), [How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) and/or [How to Use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) for more details

> Should I put the code for the popup within the actionPerformed method or make a separate method and call it somewhere else?

Well, that's up to you.  Personally, I like re-usable code, so using another method or class would be my preferred solution, but that will come down to your own context and needs